# django and editable and multiselect choices in ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, choicefield

I'm trying to get a field of model in Django, which will behave like a ChoiceField but:

- will support multiselect
- would allow to edit the list of choices

For example - I've got a product, which belongs to several cathegoris: nice, for boys, for men and so on. One product could belong to several categories. Categories can vary across the time.

Currently I'm using MultiSelectField from djang-multiselectfield, which - obviously - handles the first issue.

Is there a ready to use app, which also supports edition of choice list? Or what would be the easiest approach to achieve that?

Comment: When/where do you want to edit the choice list? Will `limit_choices_to` do anything for you?

Comment: I've added an example